# Factors that affect the speed of body?

Tags: forces

I want to know that what are scientific factors that restrict cars to overcome 450km/hr?

Comment: There are only engineering factors.

Comment: What factor like friction, weight of the body, etc dmckee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a physical limit .
Common limiting factor : price .

limited by available roads, fuel tank capacity versus range, and price :  [top 10 (under 450km/h)](http://top10mais.org/top-10-carros-mais-rapidos-do-mundo/)

[Thrust 2 is the fastest car in the world - 1228 km/h;  in construction - Bloodhound SSC - 1600 km/h](http://www.sitedecuriosidades.com/curiosidade/a-maior-velocidade-alcancada-em-solo-pelo-homem.html) 
limited by price, test sites, ground and air friction : aluminium wheels

Given enough energy, we can move a-not-a-car faster then the  Apollo 10 record for the highest speed attained by a manned vehicle at 39897 km/h .

Answer (score 1):

Defining a "car" as something that rolls on three or more wheels (two wheels is a motorcycle), there are a handful of non-production cars that have driven well past 450 kph on non-roads. A tiny number have even broken the sound barrier. The price of those non-production cars is atmospheric, as is their fuel consumption (e.g., 150 liters per minute, at idle).

My own car supposedly has a top speed in excess of 310 kph. ("Supposedly" because I haven't come anywhere close to that in my own driving. I'm thinking of renting some time on a track this fall when the weather cools down.) One of the things done in testing that car was to fill the tank full of gas and drive at top speed until the tank was empty. It took about half an hour, but the engine didn't overheat. Having to fill the tank every half hour is rather impractical and rather expensive.

Merely fast cars (e.g., mine) are expensive, impractical, dangerous, and require well-engineered roads. (You don't drive fast on a roadway full of potholes and bumps.) But oh, are they fun to drive. Extremely fast cars are extremely expensive, extremely impractical, extremely dangerous, and require extremely well-engineered roads.